# Bad Request for Field Slot Error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
name = namebox.getText().toString();
db.open();
Cursor c1 = db.executequery("SELECT _id FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_CUSTOMER + " where name='" +name+"'" );
_id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("name"));
Cursor c2 = db.executequery("SELECT amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_CUSTOMER
        +
        " where _id=" + _id);
Double amount = c2.getDouble(c2.getColumnIndex("amount"));
Cursor c3 = db.executequery("SELECT arrear FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_CUSTOMER + " where CUSTOMER_ID =" + _id);
arrear = c3.getDouble(c3.getColumnIndex("arrear"));
db.close();
```

This is giving me a bad request for field error. The method executequery on my adapter looks like this:

```
public Cursor executequery(String query) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what Im doing wrong. Im new at this.

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being inconsistent when dealing with `Cursor1`.  `getColumnIndex("name")` cannot succeed because IDs, not names are being SELECTed.  It should read `getColumnIndex("_id")`.

Comment: Thanks I noticed it myself some time later. :)